# accessing user defined pipeline variables within definitions steps bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

Im trying pass a user defined variable from a custom pipeline to a step defined within the definitions section.

My yml snippet is below:

```
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &TagVersion
        trigger: manual
        script:
          - export VERSION=$VERSION
          - echo "VERSION $VERSION"
```

```
  custom:
    run_custom:
      - variables:
          - name: VERSION
      - step:
          script:
            - echo "starting"
      - parallel:
          - step: 
              <<: *TagVersion
              variables:
                VERSION: $VERSION
```

When I build the pipeline I can see the variable is listed as a pipeline variable when running the step TagVersion, and the correct value is shown there but dont know how to use this within the scripts section where im trying to echo out the value.

thanks

Comment: I see nothing wrong on how you are using the variable besides the fact that the `step.variables` definition is undocumented and probably (at-best) ignored by bitbucket pipelines. What is the outcome of this script?